# Django url giving error

Tags: python, django

Hey I am getting this error when I try to run my Django server
"django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

```
ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern [<RegexURLPattern help_viewer ^help/$>, <RegexURLPattern help_viewer ^help/(\w+)$>, <RegexURLPattern contact ^contact/$>, <RegexURLPattern xml ^api/xml$>, <RegexURLPattern calendar ^calendar(?:.ics)?$>, <RegexURLPattern index ^$>, <RegexURLPattern quick_login ^quick_login$>, <RegexURLPattern update_indi ^update_indi$>, <RegexURLPattern settings ^settings$>, <RegexURLPattern event_list ^event_list$>, <RegexURLPattern member_list ^member_list/$>, <RegexURLPattern member_list ^member_list/(\d+)/$>, <RegexURLPattern team_list ^team_list/$>, <RegexURLPattern team_list ^team_list/(\d+)/$>, <RegexURLPattern join_team ^join_team$>, <RegexURLPattern view_team ^teams/(\d+)/$>, <RegexURLPattern update_team ^teams/(\d+)/update/$>, <RegexURLPattern edit_chapter ^edit_chapter$>, <RegexURLPattern chapter_info ^chapter_info$>, <RegexURLPattern member_fields ^member_fields/(\w+)?$>, <RegexURLPattern attendance ^attendance$>, <RegexURLPattern chapter_list ^config/chapter_list$>, <RegexURLPattern edit_events ^config/events/(MS|HS)/$>, <RegexURLPattern eventset_list ^config/eventsets/$>, <RegexURLPattern edit_eventset ^config/eventsets/(\d+)/$>, <RegexURLPattern tsa.events.views.login_view ^accounts/login/$>, <RegexURLPattern tsa.events.views.logout_view ^accounts/logout/$>, <RegexURLPattern tsa.events.views.create_account ^accounts/create/$>, <RegexURLPattern tsa.events.views.request_chapter ^accounts/request_chapter/$>, <RegexURLPattern tsa.events.views.reset_password ^accounts/reset/$>] is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
events.SystemLog.text: (fields.E121) 'max_length' must be a positive integer.
events.SystemLog.type: (fields.E121) 'max_length' must be a positive integer.
```

"

I do not know what is wrong.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from events import views as vie
 from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_reset
import config

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

handler404 = 'tsa.events.views.custom404'
handler500 = 'tsa.events.views.custom500'

urlpatterns = [

#url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^help/$',vie.help_viewer ,name='help_viewer'),
url(r'^help/(\w+)$',vie.help_viewer ,name='help_viewer'),

url(r'^contact/$',vie.contact ,name= 'contact'),

url(r'^api/xml$',vie.xml ,name='xml'),
url(r'^calendar(?:.ics)?$',vie.calendar ,name='calendar'),

# Account/Event Management Views
url(r'^$', vie.index ,name='index'),
url(r'^quick_login$',vie.quick_login ,name= 'quick_login'),
url(r'^update_indi$',vie.update_indi ,name= 'update_indi'),
url(r'^settings$',vie.settings ,name= 'settings'),

# List Views
url(r'^event_list$',vie.event_list ,name= 'event_list'),
url(r'^member_list/$',vie.member_list ,name= 'member_list'),
url(r'^member_list/(\d+)/$',vie.member_list ,name= 'member_list'),
url(r'^team_list/$',vie.team_list ,name= 'team_list'),
url(r'^team_list/(\d+)/$',vie.team_list ,name= 'team_list'),

# Team Views
url(r'^join_team$',vie.join_team ,name= 'join_team'),
url(r'^teams/(\d+)/$',vie.view_team ,name= 'view_team'),
url(r'^teams/(\d+)/update/$',vie.update_team ,name= 'update_team'),

# Chapter Admin
#url(r'^event_log$',vie. ,name= 'system_log'),
url(r'^edit_chapter$',vie.edit_chapter ,name= 'edit_chapter'),
url(r'^chapter_info$',vie.chapter_info ,name= 'chapter_info'),
url(r'^member_fields/(\w+)?$',vie.member_fields ,name= 'member_fields'),
url(r'^attendance$',vie.attendance ,name= 'attendance'),
#url(r'^email$',vie.email ,name= 'chapter_email'),


# System Admin
url(r'^config/chapter_list$',vie.chapter_list ,name= 'chapter_list'),
url(r'^config/events/(MS|HS)/$',vie.edit_events ,name= 'edit_events'),
url(r'^config/eventsets/$',vie.eventset_list ,name= 'eventset_list'),
url(r'^config/eventsets/(\d+)/$',vie.edit_eventset ,name= 'edit_eventset'),


url(r'^accounts/login/$',vie.login_view ,name= 
'tsa.events.views.login_view'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$',vie.logout_view ,name= 
'tsa.events.views.logout_view'),
url(r'^accounts/create/$',vie.create_account ,name= 
'tsa.events.views.create_account'),
url(r'^accounts/request_chapter/$',vie.request_chapter ,name= 
'tsa.events.views.request_chapter'),
url(r'^accounts/reset/$',vie.reset_password ,name= 
'tsa.events.views.reset_password'),
#url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

],
```

Comment: plz provide urls.py and other details

Comment: @SandeepLade I just updated it with the url.py

Comment: You should fix the ckearly stated errors first, which is the `max_length` of `events.SystemLog.text` and `events.SystemLog.type`. BTW `type` is not a goid choice of name. It might clash with the built-in `type()`.

Comment: @KlausD. How would I fex the max_length problem

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your models, you have a field with a negative or 0 `max_length`. To fix that, change it to a positive int as suggested by the error message.

Comment: The error message is very clear, isn't it?

Comment: @KlausD. Even better that I am the second programmer on this after the first one left leaving behind no comments of use or documentation

Answer (score 1):

There's a dangling comma at the end of the `urlpatterns` list.

Comment: Is that really it

Comment: @EthanBaxter With the comma after the closing `]`, your `urlpatterns` is a tuple containing a single item.

Comment: @Wyatt I removed the ending , and it fixed it now it is a max_length must be a positive integer

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `,` (comma) at the end, remove it and try.